# Как вывести из базы данных комментарии разным цветом?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, css

У меня записи выводятся из базы данных обычным способом через функцию while(), мне нужно чтобы записи выводились с подсветкой как показано на фото ниже из заданных цветов, и как это лучше сделать на js или на php ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php   
include ("connect.php");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($data)){      
   echo $row[name]."<br>"; 
   echo $row[text]; 
}   
?>

<script>
    var color = ["#9FD477", "#46CFB0", "#4FC2E5", "#5E9DE6", "#AD93E6"];
</script>
```

Comment: Однозначно на php, и желательно записывать стек цветов в бд, когда захотите поменять цвета гемороя не будет...

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, почему "однозначно"? Данные могут через ajax подгружаться, а подгружаться они будут в сыром виде, поэтому здесь через js надо будет цвет устанавливать.

Comment: @BOPOH а куда ваш ajax будет звонить? в рельсу? будет звонить php. Учитесь воспринимать вещи глубже. Смысл не в php, а в том что настройки должны быть в бд.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, при чем здесь настройки, если спрашивают про задание цвета определенным тегам? Можно через php это сделать во время формирования страницы, но ведь страница может формироваться по данным, полученным через ajax. А возвращать отформатированные данные через ajax - плохая идея. А вы говорите "однозначно"

Comment: Перестанте ругаться лучше помогите решить задачу на мой взгляд лучше на js.

Comment: С чего вы взяли что автору нужен ajax? Автор вы не поможете нам понимать вас лучше? И что хочет автор что бы мы написали ему генератор новостей или помогли ему с тем что у него есть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так. Попробуйте. 
Каждому комментарию присваивается случайный цвет. Можно сделать подобным образом по порядку.

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($data)){
    $color = array("#9FD477", "#46CFB0", "#4FC2E5", "#5E9DE6", "#AD93E6");
    $mycolor = array_rand($color) ;
    echo $row[name]."<br>";
    echo '<span style="color: '.$color[$mycolor].'">'.$row[text].'</span>';
}
?>
```

По порядку:

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");

$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($data)){
    if ($i == 5) $i = 0 ;
    $color = array("#9FD477", "#46CFB0", "#4FC2E5", "#5E9DE6", "#AD93E6");
    echo $row[name]."<br>";
    echo '<span style="color: ' . $color[$i] . '">' . $row[text] . '</span>';
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Сработало? Или что-то еще нужно?

Comment: Ну, для начала - нет `include ("connect.php");`. Еще ты зря вот это добавил: `if ($i == 5):`. Оно вообще не то делает. А в третьих: зачем постоянно заканчивать и начинать блоки php? Это же тихий ужас.

Comment: include ("connect.php"); я просто не скопировал. вся поблема в этом куске когда if ($i == 5):я его правильно сделать не знаю. Начинаю и заканчиваю блоки php для того что в функции while() легче вносить изменения.

Comment: Я разобрался в своем скрипте, просто вставил <?php if ($i == 5) $i = 0 ; ?> и все заработало. Спасибо за два хороших варианта сделать подсветку.