# Подгрузка комментариев разным цветом

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подгрузка комментариев через `ajax` разным цветом (10 цветов ). Этот вопрос является продолжением [**вопроса**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439745/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC), который я задавал, но так и не получил ответ, как именно это сделать на `js`. Хотя один из пользователей привел два хороших примера как можно сделать на `php`. Но мне больше подходит именно на `js`. Какие есть варианты, как сделать подсветку на стороне пользователя, то есть на `js`.

Comment: Казалось бы причем здесь ajax? Ajax вам не графическая библиотека за цвета не отвечает.

Comment: @cpp_user Я имел в виду как можно сделать подсветку на `js` на подобии как в ответе на `php`.

Comment: Подсветку чего? Вы не можете через jQuery поменять стиль элемента и поставить вам нужный color?

Answer (score 1):

Можно даже на обычном CSS:

```
<style>
/* первый в группе с 5 */
span:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
 background:#9FD477;
}
/* второй в группе с 5 */
span:nth-of-type(5n+2) {
 background:#46CFB0;
}
/* третий в группе с 5 */
span:nth-of-type(5n+3) {
 background:#4FC2E5;
}
/* четвертый в группе с 5 */
span:nth-of-type(5n+4) {
 background:#5E9DE6;
}
/* пятый в группе с 5 */
span:nth-of-type(5n) {
 background:#AD93E6;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Хороший вариант. Можно сделать подсветку в конкретном div блоке например: `<div id="con"><span>111</span><span>222</span><span>333</span></div>`.

Comment: Только если у вас три разных цвета а не 5 как по той ссылке, тогда используйте `3n` вместо `5n`